# Connect to FTP with a web browser for uploading files with WebClient.UploadFile: This method is not supported

Tags: c#, file-upload, ftp, webclient

my question is simple. i know that. but i couldn't achieve that Anyway;look please below code. how can i solve this problem. what is wrong with me?

```
System.Net.WebClient webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();

string webAddress = "http://82.21.173.134/Test/";
string destinationFilePath = webAddress + dllName;
webClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxxx", "wR@$xxxx");
webClient.UploadFile("ftp://xxxx@82.21.173.134/Test", "PUT", sourceFilePath);
webClient.Dispose();
```

> **ERROR :** {"An exception occurred during a WebClient request."} Detail : {"This method is not supported.\r\nParameter name: value"}

Answer (score 0):

- For FTP protocol, you use `STOR`, not `PUT`. You better use the overload of the [`UploadFile` method that takes the `address` and `fileName` only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploadfile#system-net-webclient-uploadfile(system-string-system-string)) (and implies the default method for the respective protocol).
- Though you possibly want to do something completely else. It's not clear what your reference to "web browser" and the `webAddress` variable (which you are not using at all) mean.